# Can coffeescript be used alongwith HTML5,CSS3 to create/develop Android applications?

Tags: android, ios, html, css, coffeescript

i am in splits whether to learn coffescript or not.Can i use coffeescript with HTML5 and CSS3 for developing applications for android and ios? As we know that we can develop android/ios apps using javascript,html5,css3. please be precise answering this question, if you have any resources on this, you're most welcome.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

CoffeeScript *always* compiles to plain JavaScript. For this reason, pretty much anything you can do with JavaScript, you can do with CoffeeScript. In the case of writing mobile apps, there's usually an additional build step in your build process that converts the CoffeeScript to JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks Brandon. So what other things do i need to go through for building an mobile app using CoffeeScript,html5,css3. if you could give me brief about this or any resource link which could help me in any way.

Comment: You can simply take any instructions for doing this with JavaScript add add a "Compile CoffeeScript" step. CoffeeScript has a built-in compiler that can compile `.coffee` files any time they change--`coffee -c -w [files]`

Comment: So basically i just need to compile my coffeescript  file to javascript and then deploy html,css and js files for andoid app right?. By the way i am going to learn node.js from your nodecasts.Looking forward to more videos from you over there. Thanks Brendon

Comment: Yeah, that's the gist of it--specifics of course depend on the actual tool you're using to make your app. Hope you enjoy the 'Casts, thanks for checking 'em out!